# Override Theme-Options.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a difficult time removing the calling from my parents theme-options.php. My problem is this: My parent theme calls for the logo not from the header.php which I could easily replace but from the theme-options.php by placing the url path to the image like so 
   `require ( get_template_directory() . '/settings/theme-options.php' );`
I want to "unrequire" this call in the child theme and add a function to call 
`require ( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/theme-options.php' );`
 This way I can modify the options file and remove the call to the url. I have had a similar problem before and fixed it by using the `unregister` function but I am not sure on how to "unrequire" this call to the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

After searching a little deeper there is a function that calls the default values like so :

```
function max_magazine_default_options() {
$options = array(
    'logo_url' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png',
    'favicon_url' => '',
    'rss_url' => '',
    'show_slider' => 1,
    'slider_category' => 0,
    'show_carousel' => 1,
    'carousel_category'=> 0,
    'show_feat_cats' => 1,
    'feat_cat1'=> 0,
    'feat_cat2'=> 0,
    'feat_cat3'=> 0,
    'feat_cat4'=> 0,
    'show_posts_list' => 1,
    'show_author' => 1,
    'show_page_comments' => 1,
    'show_media_comments' => 1,
    'ad468' => '<a href='.get_site_url().'><img src='.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/ad468.png /></a>',
    'inline_css' => '',
    'meta_desc' => '',
    'stats_tracker' => '',
    'google_verification' => '',
    'bing_verification' => '',
);
return $options;
```

}

So im guessing I could remove this function and replace it with my own and alter the values?

Comment: As @AndrewRyno says bellow, how is this `max_magazine_default_options` function being called?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you would be able to do this without editing the parent is if they call `require()` within a function called by a hook such as `init`, `setup_theme`, etc. Then you could simply do:

```
remove_action( 'hook', 'their_function_name' );
```

And then you would have to copy/paste the function into your `functions.php` file, edit it, and then re-add it using the same hook:

```
add_action( 'hook', 'your_function_name' );
```

You may also have to make sure the priority (third argument) is correct on your function to make sure it properly overrides it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew in the theme-options.php there is a function that calls on the default values and I have added the information above.

Comment: So it also depends how that function is being called. Is it called by an `add_action` or something?